# I created a function that creates objects, I want the objects created from that function to have a unique key. How can I do that?

Tags: javascript, function, object

In the `pAequorFactory()`, when invoking that function to create  an object. I want the `.specimenNum` to be unique for all objects. Check the code below

```
const pAequorFactory = (specimenNum, dna) => {
  return {
    specimenNum,
    dna,

    mutate() {
      randomBaseIndex = Math.floor[Math.random * 15];
      mutatedBase = returnRandBase();
      if (this.dna[randomBaseIndex] !== mutatedBase) {
        this.dna[randomBaseIndex] === mutatedBase;
        return this.dna;
      } else {
        mutate();
      }
    },

    compareDNA(object) {
      for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        let j = 0;
        if (object.dna[i] === this.dna[i]) {
          j++;
        }
        let commonPercentage = (j / 15) * 100;
      }
      return `specimen #${this.specimenNum} and specimen #${object.specimenNum} have ${commonPercentage}% DNA in common`;
    },

    willLikelySurvive() {
      for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        let j = 0;
        if (this.dna[i] === "C" || this.dna[i] === "G") {
          j++;
        }
        let survivePercentage = (j / 15) * 100;
      }
      return survivePercentage >= 60;
    },
  };
};
```

I haven't tried anything yet but I am thinking of a way to compare `.specimenNum` of each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The best way is to use closure**

```
const pAequorFactory = () => {
  let specimenCount = 0; // To keep track of the number of specimens created

  return (dna) => {
    specimenCount++; // Increment the specimen count for each new specimen
    return {
      specimenNum: specimenCount, // Assign a unique specimen number
      dna,

      // Your remaining object properties here
    };
  };
};

// Example usage:
const createSpecimen = pAequorFactory();
const specimen1 = createSpecimen('ATCGATCGATCGATC');
const specimen2 = createSpecimen('GCTAGCTAGCTAGCT');

console.log(specimen1.specimenNum);
console.log(specimen2.specimenNum);
```

This will create unique object each time you call createSpecimen, unique property will be specimenNum.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you did... Why did you return a function with dna as a parameter and inside the original pAequorFactory, you removed the parameters... Can you explain what you did there.

Comment: I have created one closure here with specimenCount variable, it will keep the reference of specimenCount every time you call createSpecimen method and it will increase the value to +1.

for more understanding you can quickly go through the concept of closure that how it works

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closure-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a numeric value and increment it. If you use modules it will be encapsulated in a module.

```
let specimenNumCount = 0;
export const pAequorFactory = dna => {
  return {
    specimenNum: ++specimenNumCount,
    dna,

...
```